# How to search a CSV file with php by checking if a date falls between 2 ranges

Tags: php, csv

I made a previous post that was too vague. I've done a lot of research and think I can be more specific.

```php
while (!feof($file_handle)) 
{
    $loansinfo = fgetcsv($file_handle);
    // Make sure we only check data for the game we posted
    if($loansinfo[0]==$ID) { 
        $referenceDate = $WantedDate;
        $fromDate = "$loansinfo[5]";
        $toDate = "$loansinfo[6]";
        // Convert dates to timestamps (strings to integers)
        $referenceTimestamp = strtotime( $referenceDate );
        $fromTimestamp = strtotime( $fromDate );
        $toTimestamp = strtotime( $toDate );
        $isBetween = $referenceTimestamp >= $fromTimestamp and $referenceTimestamp <= $toTimestamp;
        //refuse booking    
        echo('<script type="text/javascript">alert("Game Already Booked");</script>');
        exit;
    }
}
// otherwise execute save code
```

Problem is, I always get **'Game already booked'**. Why?

Sample CSV file data as requested:

```
ID, GameName,GameCost, DaysRequested, Total, ReservationStart, DateEnd
5,Pinball, 3.99,7, 27.99, 01/01/2015, 08/01/2015
```

Though it should be said that the form requires date entry as `YYYY-MM-DD`. I have java script that does the conversion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use PHP to make a simple booking system using CSV files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104804/how-to-use-php-to-make-a-simple-booking-system-using-csv-files)

Comment: There was a very long discussion yesterday around the same question from the same user "Student" that has been closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104804/how-to-use-php-to-make-a-simple-booking-system-using-csv-files

Comment: @bub I have tried very hard to pin point the problem and resolved one of the problems I asked about my code yesterday i.e. how to prevent my form being wiped when I tried to calculate the return date. I researched into java script and found a work around.  The java script is not posted here as irrelevant to the question. I have worked pretty much solid on this since

Comment: Hopefully, you will see research here and a clearer idea of how the original problem can be solved

Comment: post a sample of your csv file...

Comment: @MattCan Thank you for the help. I tested the code by trying to book GameID 5 (same as the CSV data shown above) but on the 2015-01-09 so as not to double book, but still get the message that the game is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this one! Try this:

```
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        $loansinfo = fgetcsv($file_handle);
        if($loansinfo[0]==$ID){
                $FromDate = "$loansinfo[5]";
                $ToDate ="$loansinfo[6]";
                if (strtotime($DateBorrowedFrom) <= strtotime($WantedDate)) {
                    if(strtotime($ToDate) >= strtotime($WantedDate)){
                        $CantBook = True;
                        }
                }
                else {
                    if (strtotime($DateBorrowedFrom)  <= strtotime($DateTo)) {
                        $CantBook= true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        fclose($file_handle);

        if($CantBook = true){
            echo('<script type="text/javascript">alert("Game is already Booked");</script>');
            }
        else{
    //Saving the booking
```

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your code, you are not checking the result of `$isBetween`.

Here is a modified version that will get you a lot closer, assuming your dates are formatted correctly.

```php
while (!feof($file_handle)) 
{
    $loansinfo = fgetcsv($file_handle);
    // Make sure we only check data for the game we posted
    if($loansinfo[0]==$ID) { 
        $referenceDate = $WantedDate;
        $fromDate = "$loansinfo[5]";
        $toDate = "$loansinfo[6]";
        // Convert dates to timestamps (strings to integers)
        $referenceTimestamp = strtotime( $referenceDate );
        $fromTimestamp = strtotime( $fromDate );
        $toTimestamp = strtotime( $toDate );
        $isBetween = $referenceTimestamp >= $fromTimestamp and $referenceTimestamp <= $toTimestamp;

        if($isBetween == true) {
            //refuse booking    
            echo('<script type="text/javascript">alert("Game Already Booked");</script>');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, coincidence..I just tried that then saw this post. I think you're spot on though...this is definitely a major improvement.  The isBetween was set but not doing anything.  I wonder if the the date conversion is whats causing the problem. I've used some java script and things might have got muddled.