# How to search a CSV file with php to prevent double booking

Tags: php

I made a previous post that was too vague. I've done a lot of research and think I can be more specific.

```
/Ready to Save? Store all data into variables
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $ID = $_POST['gameID'];
        $GameName = $_POST['gameName'];
        $GameCost = $_POST['gameCost'];
        $Days = $_POST['days'];
        $Total = $_POST['total'];
        $WantedDate = $_POST['reservationStart'];
        $DateTo = $_POST['DateEnd'];
        $StudentName = $_POST['studentName'];
while (!feof($file_handle)) 
    {
    $loansinfo = fgetcsv($file_handle);
// Make sure we only check data for the game we posted. $WantedDate is also a posted variable
        if($loansinfo[0]==$ID) { 
            $referenceDate = $WantedDate;
            $fromDate = "$loansinfo[5]";
            $toDate = "$loansinfo[6]";
// Convert dates to timestamps (strings to integers)
            $referenceTimestamp = strtotime( $referenceDate );
            $fromTimestamp = strtotime( $fromDate );
            $toTimestamp = strtotime( $toDate );
$isBetween = $referenceTimestamp >= $fromTimestamp and $referenceTimestamp <= $toTimestamp;
            if($isBetween == true) {
            //refuse booking    
            echo('<script type="text/javascript">alert("Game Already Booked");</script>');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
otherwise execute save code
```

Problem is, I always get 'Game already booked'. Why?

Comment: The ` if($loansinfo[0]==$ID)` test is always returning true.  Possibly both variables are empty?

Comment: You're setting `$isBetween`, but you're not using it anywhere. At the moment, as long as `($loansinfo[0]==$ID)`, the statement will always come back to you, as there are no other logical checks in the script

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Hitting the submit button posts the gameID, so I'm trying to check first if that game appears in the csv file, if it does, then I want to perform the date checks

Comment: @Anuji This could be the problem. As a newbie I thought that isBetween will return true? How do I employ the statement therefore?

Comment: where is `$WantedDate` being defined, and why are you continually doing a strtotime on it, since the avlue doesn't change anywhere inside the loop?

Comment: @Marc B sorry - I was trying to show only the absolute minimum code. I've added the post information when the form is submitted

Comment: thank you for all the help - you wouldnt believe how grateful I am. This is really putting me through my paces

Comment: I wonder if this would have been better as an edit to your [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30121721/472495)? The danger of having two open questions for the same problem is that people may answer one, not knowing that something very similar has been posted on the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code cleaned up with anything not actually used in the code removed:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $referenceTimestamp = strtotime($_POST['reservationStart']);
    while(!feof($file_handle)) 
    {
        $loansinfo = fgetcsv($file_handle);
        if($loansinfo[0] == $_POST['gameID'] && $referenceTimestamp >= strtotime($loansinfo[5]) && $referenceTimestamp <= strtotime($loansinfo[6])) 
        { 
            echo('<script type="text/javascript">alert("Game Already Booked");</script>');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

It checks two things: 
1. Whether the gameID matches.
2. Whether reservation start is greater than or equal to $loansinfo[5] and also lesser than or equal to $loansinfo[6].

Hopefully clearing up the debris will help.

Comment: oh yes - that's far more concise and really helpful. However, I'm still getting the 'Game Already Booked' message even when I use test data that should allow me to make a reservation

Comment: Probably would have to see an example of the csv file to troubleshoot that.